# How to test webservice for unicode handling

Tags: utf-8, internationalization, globalization

Are there test tools available to test if a webservice can handle unicode utf-8 encoded posts? How do I generate utf-8 encoded data?

Answer (score 0):

The sad-but-true answer is that there is no way to know what encoding some program expects if they don't either document it, or provide encoding metadata in whatever protocol you're using.

As for generating utf-8, well, that depends on what programming language you're using.